# Insert/replace hash value: "Hexadecimal string contains non-hex character"

Tags: bash, sed, hex, h2

I was given a dump of a MySQL database and would like to load it into H2 in MySQL mode. It is working well so far except for the "users" table, which has hashed passwords in it and gives this error:

```
'Hexadecimal string contains non-hex character: "UQ�m������l�a_x"; 
SQL statement:INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (2,16,'him','UQ�m������l�a_x', ...);
```

Since they are not useful in this case, I could replace these hex strings with any other text value. Can I do that with sed, for instance?

I tried this: `sed -e "s/'[\d128-\d255]'//g` but it replaced 95% of my file.

I have seen answers preparing JDBC statements, but I have no hand on that (these are auto-applied "evolutions" of the Play framework).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove non-ascii text you can use `tr` or `sed` , here is one basic example using `tr` :

```
 echo -e "\xA9 "This is acsii text" \xA7 \xA3 \xA1 \xA2"
© This is acsii text § £ ¡ ¢
```

Not ascii chars removed : using `tr -c -d '[[:alnum:]]|[[:space:]]|[:punct:]]'`

```
echo -e "\xA9 "This is acsii text" \xA7 \xA3 \xA1 \xA2"   |tr -c -d '[[:alnum:]]|[[:space:]]|[[:punct:]]'
 This is acsii text
```

OR

```
echo -e "\xA9 "This is acsii text" \xA7 \xA3 \xA1 \xA2"   |tr -cd '\000-\177'
 This is acsii text
```

Comment: Using the tr version, it gives now "Hexadecimal string with odd number of characters: "UQmla_x"" :( But it works, you answered the question.

Comment: Although it worked in my use case, I believe there is a bracket missing near ":punct:" : `[[:alnum:]]|[[:space:]]|[[:punct:]]`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the other answer, I managed to have it working in sed (adding the possibility to replace) as follows:

```
sed -E -e "s/[^[:alnum:][:space:][:punct:]]//g"
```